# Identify which tree nodes are leaves in lazy load WCF REST API

Tags: sql, wcf, linq, entity-framework, common-table-expression

**Using**: SQL Server 2008, WCF 4 REST, EF

I have an adjacency list table representing a tree

```
TABLE Category
(
    CatId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentId int NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

I am creating a WCF REST API to allow the client to build the tree in a lazy load way.  Doing the query to get the children of a node (nodeid below) is straight-forward.  What i'm running into is the need to identify which nodes are leaf nodes.  (*Note*: I've removed all error handling, count = 0 handling, null handling, etc. from the code below)

```
tree = _context.Categories
               .Where(c => c.ParentId == nodeid)
               .Select(p => new TreeNode
               {
                   id = p.CatId,
                   parentId = p.ParentId ?? -1,  // -1 = NULL in data struct
                   name = p.Name,
                   isleaf = true  // how to figure this out?
               }).ToList();
```

Any ideas?  I'm OK going to a stored proc for this query and have thought of using CTE, but i don't want to recurse through the entire tree - just get the children of the specified node.

**EDIT (20 Jan, 10:40am)**
I've decided to alter the DB Schema to add the "IsLeaf" bit column.  I then did an update to set the IsLeaf accordingly - which means i don't have to dynamically figure it out at runtime.  Probably more efficient, but I'm still curious how i would go about it.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no recursive functions in LINQ (yet?). So while it's somewhat easy in MSSQL, in LINQ I'd suggest doing the following (pseudocode):

```
// These two lines is one LINQ statement
level = select all root nodes (ParentID == NULL) 
add level nodes to result 
// C# loop
while level is not empty
  // The loop body except for the assignment in the end is one LINQ statement
  next = select all nodes that have parentId in level
  for each node in next
    find parent node
    add to result with updated parent info
  // C# assignment
  level = next
```

As you may see it's a combination of LINQ and C#. Also it may worth bringing the content of the table locally before doing all this.

Also you may need to update the algo to check for cycles if necessary.